# android: How to work with CoordinatorLayout and translucent navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have been studying the new google support design library. I am struggling how to make the navigation bar translucent and show content of recyclerView beneath the bar.

I am testing on a 5.1 nexus 5. I used below project as a testing project. 
sample code from Chris Banes: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

I added below to styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

to make the navigation bar translucent.

But, I can't make the CoordinatorLayout and its content, recyclerView,  showing beneath the bar.

What I want:

1. recyclerView shows under navigation bar
2. quick return is there and when the appbar is hidden, it should not go underneath the translucent status bar. status bar should be able to fully hide the scrolled up part.

Comment: Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: that will make the recyclerView showing beneath the bar. but the UI is messed up. 1. the appbar which is scrolled up will show beneath the translucent status bar. That is not what i want. 2. when the recyclerView is scrolled down to bottom, it only shows the last item in half.

Answer (score 3):

There's a related issue on Android's issue tracker, however it specifically states `API level 21`:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069

If on your device the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` works, but the only issue is the `RecyclerView` not showing behind the status-bar, try setting

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

On the `RecyclerView` or maybe one of its parents